# Setting font size and margins for examples using covington and dgruyter

Tags: fonts, margins, size, covington

I am writing a book using the `dgruyter` package for style and the `covington` package for creating linguistic examples. Unfortunately, the examples are not obeying the margins and font sizes as defined in the style. Anyone know how to troubleshoot?

Example code:

```
\documentclass[openany,nenglish]{book}
\usepackage[medium,print]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{covington}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[2]

\trigloss [ex,fsi={\normalfont\itshape}]{Bäne ekada eran?}
{bəne eka=da era-n}
{2.sg.poss language=nom cop.where-prs.sgS}
{What (where) is your language?}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of covington 2.1:

```tex
\setexampleoptions{leftmargin={8pt}}
```

With older versions (and still supported):

```tex
\setlength\exampleind{8pt}
```

(also documented in the `covington` manual)